# Not showing SnackBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

I tried to display snackBar at the bottom when an error occurs by using the try ... catch syntax as shown below, but for some reason, it is not displayed. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
    Widget _confirmButton() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 54,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          try {
            _tryValidation();
            resetPassword(userEmail).then(
              (value) => Get.to(
                () => CompletePasswordReset(),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            const snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: Text('아이디 또는 비밀번호가 맞지 않습니다.'),
              backgroundColor: errorColor40,
              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            );
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          }
        },
        child: Text(
          '가입여부 확인',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: baseColor10,
            fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
            fontSize: titleMedium,
          ),
        ),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: primaryColor50,
          elevation: 0,
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          side: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a Scaffold at the root of your class? Snackbar doesn't work if there is no scaffold

Comment: @RisheekMittal 
Yes, I do. That's not a problem. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to throw an error on your `_tryValidation` & `resetPassword` method/function

Right now implementation has never reach the catch statement even the snackbar is working well.

You can see here that by replacing the statement on the try block statement with

```
throw 500;
```

the snackbar is working well.

```
try {
 throw 500;
} catch (e) {
  const snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text('아이디 또는 비밀번호가 맞지 않습니다.'),
    backgroundColor: errorColor40,
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  );
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

Comment: I think that this is right answer. When I code `throw 500;`, the snackBar works again. Maybe the implementation hasn't reached the catch statement. Thank you @Paulo

Answer (score 1):

This snack bar need's context you have to pass context in method instead of using this you can use Get-X Snack bar you can use it anywhere.
Example;-

```
Get.snackbar('아이디 또는 비밀번호가 맞지 않습니다', '',
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
     );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But not a solution for this.